# AngularJS : set parent controller $scope variable from child directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, directive

I have a main controller *EventCtrl* that sets a *formData* variable on its scope.

This controller has a *setEventObject* method that overrides the *formData* object.

My purpose is to be able to call this method from child directives and apply the new variable value recursively to every scopes.

Here is the controller and its *setEventObject* function :

```
app.controller('EventCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.formData = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'tennis lesson'
  }
  $scope.events = [
    {id: 1, name: 'tennis lesson'}, 
    {id: 2, name: 'golf lesson'}, 
    {id: 3, name: 'handball lesson'}
  ];

  this.setEventObject = function(eventId) {
    angular.forEach($scope.events, function(elem) {
      if (elem.id == eventId) {
        $scope.formData = {
          id: elem.id,
          name: elem.name
        };
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Here is the associated [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WSFkjl2lYjysM0lLm41K), on clicks on links, it should set the form input and reset the *formData* variable.

Thanks for helping !

Comment: You should look at using `$broadcast` and `$on`, see the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `element.bind('click'` to listen to click. This is jQuery, and these changes are outside angular world. You need to tell angular about your change.

replace `eventCtrl.setEventObject(scope.event.id);` line with

```
scope.$apply(function () {
    eventCtrl.setEventObject(scope.event.id);
});
```

I tried the above change in your plunker and it works as expected.